# How can I use ingress with Haproxy on kuberenets cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

I want to use ingress with Haproxy in my kuberenets cluster, how should i use it?
I am have tried using it on my local system, I have used the HAproxy ingress controller in different namespace but I am getting 503 error randomly for the haproxy pod which has been created.

Answer (score 1):

try this

default backend

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: ingress-default-backend
  name: ingress-default-backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: ingress-default-backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: ingress-default-backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ingress-default-backend
        image: gcr.io/google_containers/defaultbackend:1.0
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    run: ingress-default-backend
  name: ingress-default-backend
spec:
  ports:
  - name: port-1
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    run: ingress-default-backend
```

haproxy ingress controller

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
    dynamic-scaling: "true"
    backend-server-slots-increment: "4"
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: haproxy-configmap
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    run: haproxy-ingress
  name: haproxy-ingress
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: haproxy-ingress
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: haproxy-ingress
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: haproxy-ingress
        image: quay.io/jcmoraisjr/haproxy-ingress
        args:
        - --default-backend-service=default/ingress-default-backend
        - --default-ssl-certificate=default/tls-secret
        - --configmap=$(POD_NAMESPACE)/haproxy-configmap
        - --reload-strategy=native
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
        - name: https
          containerPort: 443
        - name: stat
          containerPort: 1936
        env:
        - name: POD_NAME
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    run: haproxy-ingress
  name: haproxy-ingress
spec:
  externalIPs:
    - 172.17.0.50
  ports:
  - name: port-1
    port: 80
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 80
  - name: port-2
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 443
  - name: port-3
    port: 1936
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 1936
  selector:
    run: haproxy-ingress
```

update  externalIPs as per your environment

Comment: This is how I have files, instead I am using Service Type : Loadbalancer, but still not working.I have my cluster set up on AWS with coreos. While after some time the haproxy controller pod looses its IP and it gives 503 error